# Problem in getting readable text from html file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to scrape telegram chat history in local html file that i have downloaded. I successfully scrape the part that I want but it come with the html tags.
I just want only readable text from the html. I have tried to put .text to the list but get this error:

> name = list.find('div', class_="from_name").text
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```
import codecs
from csv import writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = codecs.open("file12.html", "r","utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="message default clearfix joined")

with open('telegramscrape.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as d:
    thewriter = writer(d)
    header = ['Name', 'Text', 'Time']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

for list in lists:
    name = list.find('div', class_="from_name")
    text = list.find('div', class_="text")
    time = list.find('div', class_="pull_right date details")

    info = [name, text, time]
    thewriter.writerow(info)
```

---

specific html part that i want to scrape

```
   <div class="pull_right date details" title="01.08.2021 12:21:34">
   12:21
   </div>

   <div class="text">
OXFORD TOWER,<br>63000 CYBERJAYA, SELANGOR (OT001)<br>Condominium for 
rent.<br>===================================<br>ASKING RENTAL: RM 
1600/Month. (Slightly Negotiable) 
<br>===================================<br><br>Property Detail:<br>- 
Type: Condominium<br>-Built Up: 1100 sqft<br>-Bedrooms: 3<br>- 
Bathrooms: 2<br>-Freehold<br>-Non Bumi Lot<br>-Vacant unit<br> 
<br>Nearby Amenities:<br>-Schools<br>-Restaurants<br>-Putrajaya 
Hospital<br>-Putrajaya Central<br>-Petrol Station<br> 
<br>Accessibilities:<br>-MEX<br>-SKVE<br><br>==================== 
<br>Ready for View!!!<br><br>Kindly Contact for further information 
&amp; viewing appointment:<br><br>Azzez Juan – 
<a href="tel:0126961111">0126961111</a>
<br>
<a href="Wasap.my/60126961111">Wasap.my/60126961111</a>
<br>REN 11111 <br>Maxcab Realty Sdn Bhd
   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `class='text'` and `class='pull_right date details'` are present in html but i don't see div tag with class `'from_name'`. I guess it is normal for it to raise `NoneType` Error.

Comment: There is no ```<div>``` tag with class name ```from_name``` in the HTML you provided. That is why the error.

Comment: Thanks guys, i have found out that the telegram chat history file has variety pattern and it cannot use to use the same python script to each file...the first html file has the div tag from_name but this one not....may i know other way to scrape telegram history chat html file..is using regex a best option...?